# how to set the state values in react input?

Tags: reactjs, forms, input, setstate, formik

can you please help me how can i show value of state in input field and  also input field is editable. i am trying many tricks but not helpful also can't find in Stackoverflow .......................................
I want show brandcode state property "BrandCode" value in  input field................................

here is brandcode return values

**brandcode : {
BrandCode: "Nick",
BrandID: 1
}**

```
state = {
        brandcode: [],
    };

 Getbrandcode(brandId) {
        getBrandCode(brandId)
            .then(res => {
                debugger;
                //console.log(res);
                this.setState({
                    brandcode: res.data.Data // i want show brandcode values in input 
                });
            });
    }
``
its a render.....
``
render() {

        // const { formikProps} = this.props
        return (
            <Formik
                enableReinitialize={true}
                initialValues={this.masterstyledata}
                onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
                    this.onSaveClick(values);
                }}


                validationSchema={this.validationSchema}
            >
                {formikProps => (
                    <>
                       
                        <Card>
                            <CardBody>
                                {this.state.isLoading && <LoadingPanel />}
                                <Row>
                                    <Col lg={12}>
                                        <Form>
                                            <FormGroup row>
                                                
                                                <Label for="Value" sm={3}>Brand</Label>
                                                <Col sm={3}>
                                                    <ComboBoxValue
                                                        data={this.state.branddesc}
                                                        style={{ width: '100%' }}
                                                        name="BrandID"
                                                        textField="text"
                                                        valueField="Value"
                                                        dataItemKey="Value"
                                                        onChange={(e) => {
                                                            this.BrandCodehandleChange(e);
                                                            formikProps.setFieldValue("BrandID", e.target.value)
                                                        }}
                                                        value={formikProps.values.BrandID}
                                                        placeholder="Brand Description"
                                                    />
                                                </Col>
                                            </FormGroup>
                                            <FormGroup row>
                                                //here i want set values
                                                <Label for="BrandCode" sm={3}>Style ID</Label>
                                                <Col sm={3}> <Input sm={3}
                                                    type="text"
                                                    name="BrandCode"
                                                    id="BrandCode"
                                                    onChange={formikProps.handleChange('MasterStyleCode')}
                                                    value={formikProps.values.MasterStyleCode}
                                                    placeholder="Enter Style Id"
                                                />
                                                    <Error>{formikProps.errors.MasterStyleCode}</Error>
                                                </Col>

                                           </FormGroup>
                                        </Form>
                                    </Col>
                                </Row>
                            </CardBody>
                        </Card>
```

Comment: what's the `this.masterstyledata` in this component? I think you should put your state instead of that, in addition, you must have a loading state to show a loading when brandID is fetching.

Comment: masterstyledata = {
        IsActive: true
    };

its a obj.. i need set brandcode state value in input field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you made a mistake in using `handleOnChage` and `onChange`, here:

```
onChange={formikProps.handleChange('MasterStyleCode')}
```

at render time this function will be executed and the result is `undefined` (*as you know because it's a void function!*), and it's not what you want here, to solve this you have to make a HOF and use `setFieldValue` if your input `name` is something different than initialValue key which you want to change it,  e.g:

```
onChange={(event) => {
   formikProps.setFieldValue('MasterStyleCode', event.target.value)
}}
```